# проблема при создании репозитория

Tags: git, github

Создала репозиторий на github и хотела клонировать ее в папку которая уже с файлами на рабочем столе. Проблема в том что когда я захожу в папку и ввожу git status он отмечает все измененные процессы в моем компе, различные программы/папки старые которые я удалила. Хотя при работе с другой папкой , локально, просто через терминал , такой проблемы не возникало. Сразу скажу папку которую я хочу залить в репозиторий я не создавала, это стартовый учебный проект.Поэтому почему в этой папке гит находит изменения в компе и отмечает их, не могу понять. Как мне исправить ошибку и почему она возникла, Спасибоо!!
Прилагаю изображение вывода при git status
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятно, в текущем каталоге не создано само хранилище. создаётся он командами init или clone. и располагается внутри подкаталога `.git`

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Comment: не помогло к сожалению, после комманды git status опять  все те же измененные файлы

Comment: На сколько понимаю, Вы в папке, содержащей некие файлы создаете новый репозиторий, а потом выполняете `git status`. Если так, то естественно, он Вам выдаст список измененных файлов, содержащий все ,что есть в этой папке. Вы же еще не добавили их в репозиторий, и в `.gitignor` тоже не внесли. Соответственно, git воспринимает все эти файлы как новые, о чем Вам и говорит.

Comment: Да Юрий , я понимаю почему он мне говорит об этом , я не понимаю другое, все операции которые он отражает были совершены задолго до появления этой папки с файлами у меня на рабочем столе.  Он по сути отражает манипуляции которые происходили в системе компа , а не в папке. Ведь обычно GIt отражает только то что происходило  в данной  папке.. правильно я понимаю?